Why does Scheme use the procedural representation of pairs?
I am reading SICP. It says in 2.1.3:

That is, the operations satisfy the condition that, for any objects x and y, if z is (cons x y) then (car z) is x and (cdr z) is y. ... Here are the definitions:
 (define (cons x y)
   (define (dispatch m)
     (cond ((= m 0) x)
           ((= m 1) y)
           (else (error "Argument not 0 or 1 -- CONS" m))))
   dispatch)

 (define (car z) (z 0))

 (define (cdr z) (z 1))

...
The point of exhibiting the procedural representation of pairs is not
that our language works this way (Scheme, and Lisp systems in general,
implement pairs directly, for efficiency reasons) but that it could work
this way. The procedural representation, although obscure, is a perfectly adequate way to represent pairs, since it fulfills the only conditions that pairs need to fulfill.

In C, we may implement "pair" using array which in assembly codes is implemented by allocating one consecutive memory addresses to store data. We can check the array size to ensure it is a pair.
Then why is "procedural representation" more efficient for Scheme?
I have learnt computer architecture. Any answers based on assembly language are welcome.

As the quoted passage says, Scheme could work this way, but it doesn't (for efficiency reasons).

Using a struct instead of an array is more common in C. Though they'd likely be the same at the level of assembly. (Let's not even go into finding the size of an array in C...)

@sepp2k Thanks. I am not one native English speaker. Some sentences in SICP seems ambiguous for me, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/78641848/21294350, although I can understand what CSAPP and OSTEP etc. say well.

It's not about efficiency: I don't know of any Scheme implementations that implement pairs this way.
It's about two things:

Expressive power.  Once you have first-class procedures it turns out they can be used to implement all sorts of other things.  You can implement pairs using them, if you want.  You might start to wonder: is there anything you can't implement using them, if you want to?
Abstraction.  The title of that section of SICP is 'Introduction to data abstraction' and it's making the point that what matters is the interface to something, not how its implemented.  So long as the interface remains the same, the implementation may not matter that much.

(The answer to the question in the first point is 'no'.)

Your point 2 is right. As sepp2k says, I understood what the author conveys wrongly.
